# Issues with layout management in Tkinter Python application

Tags: python, user-interface, layout, tkinter

I am having a real issue with a little Tkinter program I'm making in Python as a frontend to my own CMS, regarding layout of the controls on the window. I am new to Tkinter but not Python but am struggling to use the grid layout manager to arrange my controls as I want them.
Here is a (terrible) mockup of what I'm aiming for:
[image]

But my code (below) only renders this:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
'''
Configure main window controls
'''
postTtlFrame = Frame(tkRoot, bg="red")
postTtlLbl = Label(postTtlFrame, text="Page title:").grid(row=0, column=0)
postTtlEnt = Entry(postTtlFrame).grid(row=0, column=1)
postTtlFrame.grid(row=0, column=0)

postTxtFrame = Frame(tkRoot, bg="blue")
postTxtLbl = Label(postTxtFrame, text="Page body content:").grid(row=0, column=0)
postTxtArea = Text(postTxtFrame).grid(row=1, columnspan=1)
postTxtFrame.grid(row=1, column=0)

pageConfigFrame = Frame(tkRoot, bg="green")
headerDirecLbl = Label(tkRoot, text="Page header location:").grid(row=0, column=0)
headerDirecEnt = Entry(tkRoot).grid(row=0, column=1)
footerDirecLbl = Label(tkRoot, text="Page footer location:").grid(row=1, column=0)
footerDirecEnt = Entry(tkRoot).grid(row=1, column=1)
stylesDirecLbl = Label(tkRoot, text="Page stylesheet location:").grid(row=2, column=0)
stylesDirecEnt = Entry(tkRoot).grid(row=2, column=1)
outputDirecLbl = Label(tkRoot, text="Page output location:").grid(row=3, column=0)
outputDirecEnt = Entry(tkRoot).grid(row=3, column=1)
pageConfigFrame.grid(row=2, column=0)

buttonsFrame = Frame(tkRoot, bg="orange")
postBtn = Button(tkRoot, text="Post").grid(row=0, column=0)
exitBtn = Button(tkRoot, text="Exit", command=quitTk).grid(row=0, column=1)
buttonsFrame.grid(row=3, column=0)
```

Please can someone explain to me what on earth is going wrong!

Thanks in advance,
Ilmiont

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to get something pretty close to what you want :

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
content = Label(root, padx=30,pady=30,background = "white")
content.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, S, E, W))
title_frame = Label(content, borderwidth=5, relief="sunken", padx=30,pady=30,background = "white")
title_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N))
body_frame = Label(content, borderwidth=5, relief="sunken", padx=30,pady=30,background = "white")
body_frame.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=(N,W,E))
config_frame = Label(content, borderwidth=5, relief="sunken", padx=30,pady=30,background = "white")
config_frame.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=(N, W))
button_frame = Label(content, borderwidth=5, relief="sunken", padx=30,pady=30,background = "orange")
button_frame.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=(S, E))

title_entry = Entry(title_frame, background="lightblue")
title_entry.grid(column=1, row=0)
title_label = Label(title_frame,text = "Page title",background = "white")
title_label.grid(column=0,row=0)

body_text = Text(body_frame, background="lightblue")
body_text.grid(column=1,row=0)
body_label = Label(body_frame,text = "Page body content",background = "white")
body_label.grid(column=0, row=0)

header_entry = Entry(config_frame, background="lightblue")
header_entry.grid(column=1, row=0)
header_label = Label(config_frame,text = "header",background = "white")
header_label.grid(column=0,row=0)

footer_entry = Entry(config_frame, background="lightblue")
footer_entry.grid(column=1, row=1)
footer_label = Label(config_frame,text = "footer",background = "white")
footer_label.grid(column=0,row=1)

postBtn = Button(button_frame, text="Post")
postBtn.grid(row=0, column=0)
exitBtn = Button(button_frame, text="Exit")
exitBtn.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

And it displays that : [image: Tkinter output]

Concerning why your code doesn't work :
I guess it's because you defined your grid position with :

```
postTtlLbl = Label(postTtlFrame, text="Page title:").grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Instead of

```
 postTtlLbl = Label(postTtlFrame, text="Page title:")
 postTtlLbl.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

It's a problem when you expect to create an instance of your frame (by returning the instance into the `postTtlLbl` variable), because the grid method doesn't return anything so these variables handling the frame are `Nonetype`, and you can't do anything with them.

Hope it's clear.

Comment: I think this is a poor answer. It doesn't address the many problems in the code, and gives a final result that doesn't match the expected result. The alignment of the header, footer and page title are off. Finally, the GUI doesn't resize properly when you change the size of the containing window.

Comment: It addresses the problem raised by the author of the question which was : 
"I'am struggling to use the grid layout manager to arrange my controls as I want them".

Comment: I think I should rephrase my comment. What I meant to say was that this is a good start, but you could make the answer a lot better if you explained exactly what the problems with the original code. While  calling .grid during widget creation is _a_ problem, it doesn't really contribute to the problems in this question. Simply saying "here's a working example", and then have that working example only be a little better, doesn't make for a great answer. With a little effort I think you can make this answer much better.

Answer (score 1):

First off, it's pointless to assign a widget to a variable if you're calling `grid` (or `pack` or `place`) at the same time. `foo=Label(..).grid(...)` will always return `None` because `grid(...)` always returns `None`. Also, I find that layout problems are *much* easier to solve when you separate your layout from widget creation.

So, let's start by doing that:

```
'''
Configure main window controls
'''
postTtlFrame = Frame(tkRoot, bg="red")
postTxtFrame = Frame(tkRoot, bg="blue")
pageConfigFrame = Frame(tkRoot, bg="green")
buttonsFrame = Frame(tkRoot, bg="orange")

postTtlFrame.grid(row=0, column=0)
postTxtFrame.grid(row=1, column=0)
pageConfigFrame.grid(row=2, column=0)
buttonsFrame.grid(row=3, column=0)

postTtlLbl = Label(postTtlFrame, text="Page title:")
postTtlEnt = Entry(postTtlFrame).grid(row=0, column=1)
postTtlLbl.grid(row=0, column=0)

postTxtLbl = Label(postTxtFrame, text="Page body content:")
postTxtArea = Text(postTxtFrame)
postTxtLbl.grid(row=0, column=0)
postTxtArea.grid(row=1, columnspan=1)

headerDirecLbl = Label(tkRoot, text="Page header location:")
headerDirecEnt = Entry(tkRoot)
footerDirecLbl = Label(tkRoot, text="Page footer location:")
footerDirecEnt = Entry(tkRoot)
stylesDirecLbl = Label(tkRoot, text="Page stylesheet location:")
stylesDirecEnt = Entry(tkRoot)
outputDirecLbl = Label(tkRoot, text="Page output location:")
outputDirecEnt = Entry(tkRoot)
postBtn = Button(tkRoot, text="Post")
exitBtn = Button(tkRoot, text="Exit")

headerDirecLbl.grid(row=0, column=0)
headerDirecEnt.grid(row=0, column=1)
footerDirecLbl.grid(row=1, column=0)
footerDirecEnt.grid(row=1, column=1)
stylesDirecLbl.grid(row=2, column=0)
stylesDirecEnt.grid(row=2, column=1)
outputDirecLbl.grid(row=3, column=0)
outputDirecEnt.grid(row=3, column=1)
postBtn.grid(row=0, column=0)
exitBtn.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

Now, I think you can see more clearly what is happening. The problems I see are:

1. You seem to want to organize things into four main areas, but your mock-up shows that everything in the first three areas should share the same grid structure, so I'm not sure why you're creating these frames
2. You don't assign any weights to rows or columns, so they won't grow and shrink how you expect them to
3. Most of the widgets all share a common parent of `tkRoot` rather than the organizational frames that you create, so the frames end up serving no purpose
4. Because many widgets share the same parent, you end up putting several widgets on top of each other in the same grid cell.
5. You don't use the `sticky` attribute, so widgets won't fill their columns.

The fix for all this depends on exactly what effect you're trying to achieve. If you want four independent areas you need to make sure each widget has the appropriate frame for its parent, rather than lumping most widgets in the tkRoot frame. This makes it likely that, for example, the postTtlEnt won't line up with the other entry widgets.

If you *don't* want four independent areas and *do* want the postTtlEnt widget to line up with everything else, get rid of the intermediate frames and put everything into a single grid.

Likely you want a mix -- the buttons don't necessarily need to share the same grid, but all of the entry widgets *should* share the same grid. Here's how I would do it. Notice that I only have one extra internal frame, for the buttons. Everything else shares a common parent. Also notice that I give a weight to one row and one column so that you get the right resize behavior:

Here's a complete, working example. It doesn't precisely match your mockup: the exit and post buttons don't have their own dedicated column, but if you really want that you can do that if you want. The space above the buttons seems wasted, so I elected to put the buttons directly below the input widgets.

```
'''
Configure main window controls
'''

postTtlLbl = Label(tkRoot, text="Page title:")
postTxtLbl = Label(tkRoot, text="Page body content:")
headerDirecLbl = Label(tkRoot, text="Page header location:")
footerDirecLbl = Label(tkRoot, text="Page footer location:")
stylesDirecLbl = Label(tkRoot, text="Page stylesheet location:")
outputDirecLbl = Label(tkRoot, text="Page output location:")

postTtlEnt = Entry(tkRoot)
postTxtArea = Text(tkRoot)
footerDirecEnt = Entry(tkRoot)
headerDirecEnt = Entry(tkRoot)
stylesDirecEnt = Entry(tkRoot)
outputDirecEnt = Entry(tkRoot)

buttonsFrame = Frame(tkRoot, bg="orange")
postBtn = Button(buttonsFrame, text="Post")
exitBtn = Button(buttonsFrame, text="Exit")
postBtn.pack(side="right")
exitBtn.pack(side="right")

postTtlLbl.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
postTxtLbl.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
headerDirecLbl.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="w")
footerDirecLbl.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="w")
stylesDirecLbl.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky="w")
outputDirecLbl.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky="w")

postTtlEnt.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ew")
postTxtArea.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")
headerDirecEnt.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="ew")
footerDirecEnt.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky="ew")
stylesDirecEnt.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky="ew")
outputDirecEnt.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky="ew")
buttonsFrame.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky="ew", columnspan=2)

tkRoot.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
tkRoot.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I have it working now @jeanrjc, my code was FULL of errors I realise now; here is what I used in the end:

```
'''
Configure main window controls
'''
postTtlFrame = Frame(tkRoot)
postTtlLbl = Label(postTtlFrame, text="Page title:").grid(row=0, column=0)
postTtlEnt = Entry(postTtlFrame).grid(row=0, column=1)
postTtlFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

postTxtFrame = Frame(tkRoot)
postTxtLbl = Label(postTxtFrame, text="Page body content:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
postTxtArea = Text(postTxtFrame).grid(row=1, columnspan=1)
postTxtFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

pageConfigFrame = Frame(tkRoot)
headerDirecLbl = Label(pageConfigFrame, text="Page header location:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
headerDirecEnt = Entry(pageConfigFrame).grid(row=0, column=1)
footerDirecLbl = Label(pageConfigFrame, text="Page footer location:").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
footerDirecEnt = Entry(pageConfigFrame).grid(row=1, column=1)
stylesDirecLbl = Label(pageConfigFrame, text="Page stylesheet location:").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
stylesDirecEnt = Entry(pageConfigFrame).grid(row=2, column=1)
outputDirecLbl = Label(pageConfigFrame, text="Page output location:").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
outputDirecEnt = Entry(pageConfigFrame).grid(row=3, column=1)
pageConfigFrame.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

buttonsFrame = Frame(tkRoot)
postBtn = Button(buttonsFrame, text="Post").grid(row=0, column=0)
exitBtn = Button(buttonsFrame, text="Exit", command=quitTk).grid(row=0, column=1)
buttonsFrame.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=E)
```

Now I have the following result which is what I wanted:
[image]

Thanks anyway though!